# PHP Вывести период даты "с" - "по" через запятую каждый день

Tags: php

Может у кто то знает функцию или уже писал такую, стоит задача ввести период даты например указываем в форме дату с **2021-03-23** по **2021-03-26**, ее нужно вывести в формате 23 March 2021, 24 March 2021, 25 March 2021, 26 March 2021 через запятую.

Я предполагаю, нужно использовать date_parse_from_format() разобрать и циклом сделать перебор, но блин много условностей, например в январе может быть 28 так и 29 дней, а в каких-то месяцах не 30 а 31 (с этим проще) но все же )))

Может кто то делал такую задачку и есть уже готовое решение? Я пока в рунете не наткнулся, пошел искать в интерсеть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
/**
 * Creating date collection between two dates
 *
 * <code>
 * <?php
 * # Example 1
 * date_range("2014-01-01", "2014-01-20", "+1 day", "m/d/Y");
 *
 * # Example 2. you can use even time
 * date_range("01:00:00", "23:00:00", "+1 hour", "H:i:s");
 * </code>
 *
 * @author Ali OYGUR <alioygur@gmail.com>
 * @param string since any date, time or datetime format
 * @param string until any date, time or datetime format
 * @param string step
 * @param string date of output format
 * @return array
 */
function date_range($first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $output_format = 'd/m/Y' ) {

    $dates = [];
    $current = strtotime($first);
    $last = strtotime($last);

    while($current <= $last) {
        $dates[] = date($output_format, $current);
        $current = strtotime($step, $current);
    }

    return $dates;
}
```

Источник: [PHP: вернуть все даты между двумя датами в массиве](https://overcoder.net/q/334/php-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5-duplicate)

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно, Элегантное и простое решение.